# What is E[X-Y]?

Tags: probability, expected-value

I was given X~N(1,3) and Y~N(5,7) and for E[X+Y]= E[X]+E[Y], I just added the 1 and 5 and got the answer correct, but when I subtracted it for E[X-Y] I didn't get the correct answer.

I was lost thinking if E[X-Y] = E[X]-E[Y] does not exist. Can I get help on what E[X-Y] means?

Comment: Weird, it should be just $E[X] - E[Y]$

Comment: It is just $E[X]-E[Y]$.

Comment: The answer is obviously $-4$.  What did you get?

Comment: I apologize to everyone! My professor made the mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expectation is a linear operator. Just rewrite your expression as $Z=X+(-1)\cdot Y$, hence the expectation of $Z, \mathbf{E}Z = \mathbf{E}X + (-1) \cdot \mathbf{E}Y = 1+(-1)\cdot 5=-4 $